# ASP.NET - razor static variable life span?

Tags: asp.net, variables, webmatrix

I have three .cshtml created using WebMatrix:

MyClass.cshtml located at App_Code:

```
 @functions
 {
    public static string x;

    public static void setX()
    {
        x = "some data";
    }
}
```

WithSet.cshtml located at the root:

```
@{
    MyClass.setX();    
}

@MyClass.x
```

WithoutSet.cshtml located at the root:

```
@MyClass.x
```

When I visit WithSet.cshtml, MyClass.x will be set to "some data" and after that, when I visit WithoutSet.cshtml, still the  MyClass.x contains "some data". I was expecting that class to be fresh, not initialized and so MyClass.x. I think I don't fully understand what is going on, what is the life span of the class? Is the class here static?

Comment: Static variables are unique to the whole app domain on the web server, and will be persistent until application restart.

Comment: @StefanH So you mean users are sharing same data?

Comment: Correct.  Static fields should generally be avoided in a web context for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because static objects are shared across the app domain in .net - all users will get the same instance of the class with that static variable having been set.

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/avoid-static-variables-in-asp-net/

There is a good explanation of what the implications of using static fields in .net are.